# how to get event when knockout binding is done

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a problem with jquery selectmenu plugin and knockout binding. In short, I need to call selectmenu after knockout binding is done. How do I know binding of certain html element is done?

Comment: You should include the code you are attempting to use so that others may better assist you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use afterrender event for doing anything after rendering the template.

```
      <div data-bind='template: { name: "personTemplate",  data: myData, afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'> </div>

      viewModel.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements)            
       {            
             //You can add custom post-processing logic here           
       }
```