# On 'ElementHasChildren' Event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

There's a website I use which has a built in userform. The userform contains multiple drop down lists. At runtime, (on 'DOMContentLoaded'), none of the drop down lists contain any data. When opening the DDL I assume some Javascript is run to load the list into the page.

The element:

```
<ul class='hidden' data-bind='template: { name: 'childTreeTemplate', foreach: Kids }' style='display:block;'></ul>
```

After 'opening' becomes a list of 3 elements:

```
<ul class='hidden' data-bind='template: { name: 'childTreeTemplate', foreach: Kids }' style='display:block;'>
    <li class='treeItem'>...</li>
    <li class='treeItem'>...</li>
    <li class='treeItem'>...</li>
</ul>
```

**Can I set up an event to detect this?**

Things I have already tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1].addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    alert('Content Loaded')
});

document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1].addEventListener('onchange', function () {
    alert('Changed')
});

document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1].addEventListener('onload', function () {
    alert('Loaded')
});
```

None of these events trigger when the elements are loaded (i probably misunderstand their use)...

Comment: I guess you are not able to change the markup of userform? The page uses library Knockout, so the most reliable option is to make sure that your code is executed **after** `ko.applyBindings(...)` call.

Comment: If you have the possibility to change the markup then take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893291/how-to-get-event-when-knockout-binding-is-done

Comment: Sadly not able to change the markup , unless there is a simple way to alter the HTML before loading the site? Mutation observer solution below will work for my needs though. I have never heard of Knockout till now, and that'd explain why the main object is "SEOko"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

> MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a
>   DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in
>   the DOM3 Events specification.

```js
var target = document.getElementById( 'parent' );

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type==='childList') {
     alert( 'added!' );
      return false;
    }
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

document.getElementById( 'parent' ).appendChild( document.createElement( 'li' ) );
```

```html
<ul id="parent" style='display:block;'>

</ul>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q5nytv0L/

In the past I have used [`DOMNodeInserted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), but it's deprecated:

```js
document.getElementById( 'parent' ).addEventListener( 'DOMNodeInserted', function ( event ) {    
    if( event.target.parentNode.id == 'parent' ) {
        alert( 'added!' );        
    };
    
}, false );


document.getElementById( 'parent' ).appendChild( document.createElement( 'li' ) );
```

```html
<ul id="parent" style='display:block;'>

</ul>
```